# Can the CFG model Kleene star (even when it can be $\epsilon$-free)? How?

Tags: context-free

Can the context-free grammar model the Kleene star * operation of regular expressions?

If the CFG is reducible to not containing $\epsilon$ productions, as per:

```
Any context-free language can be converted into an
equivalent grammar in which at most the start variable
derives the empty string
```

then

how can it express e.g. (a|b)*?

> P -> aP
> P -> bP

?

But when would this terminate?

Comment: As you know, every regular language is context-free. If CFGs couldn't simulate Kleene star, then there would clearly be regular languages that were not context-free. Please think a little before posting questions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The question came from a "modelling" question in the context of CFG. So even that point would then be valid. But I wanted to emphasize that I was thinking this "while doing CFGs". And the given answer points out one problem (that if $\epsilon$ is forbidden).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the effect of $X \Rightarrow A^*$ you just do $X \rightarrow X A \mid \epsilon$ (or $X \rightarrow A X \mid \epsilon$, according to taste).

Yes, officially productions with $\epsilon$ (the empty string) on the right are forbidden in CFGs, but you can eliminate said productions if you want.

Comment: Do you have a source on the rule that CFGs not have $\epsilon$ on the right-hand side of the production? I've never seen that before (except in the context of finding nice normal forms.)

Comment: And what about combining $X \rightarrow XA$ and $X \rightarrow AX$? Can they exist simultaneously and then it's the parser algorithm that makes the choice in which one to match?

Comment: @mavavilj that'll make the grammar ambiguous, thus hard to parse (or you'd need a parser generator that "disambiguates")

Comment: As for grammars being $\epsilon$-free, you can't represent languages that include $\epsilon$ that way, so that's not correct. What is sometimes sought after in normal forms is not having any $\epsilon$-productions except for the start symbol.

Comment: Some definitions (including Chomsky's original one, if I recall correctly) disallow $\epsilon$ productions.

Answer (score 1):

$P \rightarrow aP$ 
  $P \rightarrow a$ 
  $P \rightarrow bP$ 
  $P \rightarrow b$ 
and ($P$ is the start symbol) 
 $P \rightarrow \epsilon$